# Exporting multiple imputed objects with MICE

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I am imputing my missing data using mice. The problem here is that it takes an hour or two to get the imputation done. So as it finishes imputing, I would like to export it for future use so that I could avoid repeating the time-consuming imputation process in case I have to revisit the analysis.

I have searched on Google and I found a function `miceadds::write.mice.imputation`. I have looked at the manual. It offered an example of exporting, but I am not sure how to import it back. It seems to have generated some .dat file.

say I have the following code:

```
# Model 1: Imputation using mice  
imp1 <- mice::mice( nhanes, m=3, maxit=5 )  
# write results 
write.mice.imputation(mi.res=imp1, name="mice_imp1" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you noticed when you use `write.mice.imputation`, its default values are to save your imputed data in various types of files (csv, spss, dat, Rdata).

We can create a sample data:
    set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(group = sample(c(1:5, NA), replace = TRUE, size = 10), 
               val = sample(c(10:15, NA), replace = TRUE, size = 10))

Load and impute our data:

```
require(mice)
require(miceadds)
imp1 <- mice::mice(df, m=3, maxit=5 )
```

Write our results:

```
write.mice.imputation(mi.res=imp1, name="mice_imp1", 
                      include.varnames=TRUE,
                      long=TRUE, mids2spss=TRUE,
                      spss.dec=",", dattype=NULL)
```

Now, we can load what ever file type is comfortable for you. For example, `dat` file:

```
oldData <- read.table("mice_imp1/mice_imp1__LONG.dat")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
est_long <- parlmice(nhanes, cluster.seed = 123, print = FALSE, n.core = 4, n.imp.core = 100) %>%
  mice::complete("long")
```

gives

```
head(est_long)
  .imp .id age  bmi hyp chl
1    1   1   1 22.0   1 131
2    1   2   2 22.7   1 187
3    1   3   1 27.2   1 187
4    1   4   3 27.2   2 284
5    1   5   1 20.4   1 113
6    1   6   3 20.4   1 184
```

You can follow up by breaking the long data set into a list of 400 data sets.

```
    est_long <- parlmice(nhanes, cluster.seed = 123, print = FALSE, n.core = 4, n.imp.core = 100) %>%
      mice::complete("long")%>%
  group_by(.imp) %>% 
  nest()  
head(est_long)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   .imp [6]
   .imp data                 
  <int> <list>               
1     1 <tibble[,5] [25 × 5]>
2     2 <tibble[,5] [25 × 5]>
3     3 <tibble[,5] [25 × 5]>
4     4 <tibble[,5] [25 × 5]>
5     5 <tibble[,5] [25 × 5]>
6     6 <tibble[,5] [25 × 5]>
```